# Why does my query return records which doesn't meet the where clause conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, subquery

I have written a query which returns records with dates that are actually older than the mentioned date.

```
Declare @DateFrom date
Set @DateFrom= '02/Oct/2019'

SELECT 1, Convert(varchar(11), AppliedDateTime, 106)
FROM [MC_Tenders].[dbo].[AppliedWorks]
Where 
Convert(varchar, AppliedDateTime,106) >= Convert(varchar, @DateFrom,106)
```

Applied dates are saved in table as datetime e.g. `2017-04-25 15:51:25.257`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing the comparison as *strings* rather than dates.  Remove the conversion:

```
SELECT 1, Convert(varchar(11), AppliedDateTime, 106)
FROM [MC_Tenders].[dbo].[AppliedWorks]
WHERE AppliedDateTime >= @DateFrom;
```

Type 106 is `dd mm yyyy`.  When you compare as strings, the *strings* are compared, not the dates.  With format 106, the *days* are compared first, so:  `'18-10-2017' < '25-12-1900'` because "1" < "2".

Answer (score 0):

Just to finish Gordon Linoff's thought, your code should look something like this:

```
SELECT 
  1
  , CAST(AppliedDateTime AS DATE) AS AppliedDate
FROM 
  [MC_Tenders].[dbo].[AppliedWorks]
WHERE 
  CAST(AppliedDateTime AS DATE) >= @DateFrom;
```

Edit: I'm assuming AppliedDateTime is actually stored as a datetime, or some data type other than DATE. The explicit CAST to the DATE type will strip out the time component and allow SQL to just compare the date component to your variable.

Comment: There is no need to cast a `datetime` to a `date` for a `>=` comparison.

Comment: A fair criticism, but the OP didn't say how the AppliedDateTime is stored. The explicit cast will (usually) work, even if the field is a string.